# When are monic polynomials of fourth degree divisible?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Note that this might be an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), therefore I'm posting the original question too.

I am asked to prove that given a monic polynomial of fourth degree which has a non-zero root, must have at least one more distinct root.

The way I hoped to solve this: claim that since there is non-zero root, the coefficient of $x^0$ must be non-zero, and hopefully, this also implies that such a polynomial must be divisible by a lower order polynomial (hopefully of second degree), and if so, it would have at least two roots which differ is sign.

Intuitively, I know this to be true, due to the shape of the quadric function (which, if it crosses the X axis at least once, must do it one more time), but I wouldn't know how to formalize this.

Comment: I'm confused by your original question.  If you have the polynomial $(x-2)^4$, it is monic of fourth degree with a nonzero root.  However, $2$ is a multiple root of degree $4$, so the polynomial doesn't have at least one more distinct root.

Comment: Note also that if a function has a root, its graph needn't "cross" the $X$ axis: it can "touch" it, instead.

Comment: @MichaelBurr fair point... I've re-read the text of assignment, and it doesn't say explicitly that the roots must be distinct, but if they shouldn't be distinct, then it's an absolute no-brainer, just by using the fundamental theorem of algebra...

Comment: @ajotatxe if the graph of quadric function touches X axis, the root will be zero, but that possibility is already excluded in the given.

Comment: No, the graph of $y=(x-2)^4$ just touches the $x$-axis, but the root isn't zero.

Comment: @MichaelBurr ouch, I was thinking of something else... yes, that's definitely true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments to the original question, the roots do not need to be distinct, so I will answer the question of why a quartic polynomial with at least one real root has at least two real roots (not necessarily distinct).

Sketch: Let $f(x)$ be a quartic polynomial (not necessarily monic) and let $a$ be a root.  Then, $(x-a)$ is a factor of $f(x)$, so $f(x)/(x-a)$ is a degree three polynomial, call it $g(x)$.  Since the leading term of $g(x)$ is of odd degree, when $x$ is a large positive number, the value of $g(x)$ has a different sign than when $x$ is a large negative number.  Therefore, the graph of $g(x)$ must cross the $x$-axis somewhere and have at least one more root.

Comment: Why should there be a leading term of odd degree? What if its coefficient is zero?

Comment: If the leading term is zero, then the original polynomial wasn't quadratic (its leading coefficient would also be zero).

Comment: Oh, so this would be basically the proof of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem, wouldn't it?

Comment: OK, that and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem. I think I've got it now. Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: $f(x)$ quadratic has a cubic quotient?

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question (as written). What question is it an answer to?

Comment: @BillDubuque In the comments to the question, the OP clarified (and corrected/changed) the question.

Comment: It seems you meant to write "quartic" not "quadratic". Also it would be helpful to state the changed version of the problem that this answers, i.e. the roots need not be distinct. One shouldn't have to read comments on a question to understand an answer!